# $\int_\Omega \phi d\mu_n\to\int_\Omega\phi d\mu,\forall\ \phi\in C_0(\Omega) $ and $\mu_n\geq 0$ implies $\mu\geq 0$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded domain and suppose that $\mu_n$ is a sequence of non-negative Radon measures, that converges to a Radon measure $\mu$ in the weak star sense: $$\int_\Omega \phi d\mu_n\to\int_\Omega\phi d\mu,\forall\ \phi\in C_0(\Omega) $$

where $C_0(\Omega)$ denotes the set of continuous compacted support functions. Can I conclude that $\mu\geq 0$?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I think. For every nonnegative $\phi\in C_o(\Omega)$ you have 
$$\int\phi \, d\mu\ge 0,$$
so $d\mu$ is a positive linear functional. You apply the Riesz Representation Theorem and you are done. Is it too easy? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Please post you comment as an answer @GiuseppeNegro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For every nonnegative $\phi\in C_o(\Omega)$ you have 
$$\int\phi \, d\mu\ge 0,$$
so $d\mu$ is a positive linear functional. By the Riesz Representation Theorem you can conclude that $d\mu\ge 0$.

Comment: Abstractly: You transfer the order from $C_0(\Omega)$ to its dual space $M(\Omega)$ using the duality: a functional is non-negative if it only takes non-negative values on non-negative elements of $C_0(\Omega)$. The set $$\{\mu \in M(\Omega) \mid \mu \geq 0\} = \bigcap_{\phi \geq 0} \{\mu \in M(\Omega) \mid \langle \phi, \mu \rangle \geq 0\}$$ is obviously weak\*-closed.

Comment: This equality of sets make things all clear @Martin.

Comment: @Tomás: Very good :-) But note that it really is the same argument as Giuseppe's, only with a slightly different emphasis and useful for generalization: if the orders in two spaces in duality are compatible with the duality pairing then the positive cone in the dual space is weak\*-closed.